# CSS how to change the color of a link within a class

Tags: html, css

I have parts of my webpage what has a dark background, what I want is that just in that part the links are white, but I tried several things, it still is the darker color

css

```
.transback {
background: rgba(7, 7, 7, 0.7); 
}
.transback a:{
color:white}
```

HTML

```
<div class="pure-u-14-24 transback">
    <a href="../gastenboek_bladeren.html">click here</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the colon after `a` in your CSS, it is not a valid selector. You can target `a` or `a:link` `a:visited` `a:hover` `a:active` but not `a:`

```css
.transback {
  background: rgba(7, 7, 7, 0.7); 
}
  .transback a {
    color:white
  }
```

```html
<div class="pure-u-14-24 transback">
    <a href="../gastenboek_bladeren.html">click here</a>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, happy to help! [More info on CSS link styling here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp).

Answer (score -1):

```
.transback a:link{
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```